# Generic class comparison

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to create a generic class Node as follow:

```
public class Node<T>
{
  public Node<T> Next;
  public Node<T> Previous;
  T Content;

  public Node<T>()
  {
  }
}
```

In my main (or from other class) I would like to compare items.. something like the following: (I use pseudo code to illustrate my idea, the code may or may not really work). Basically I would like to find if the item I have is in the list.

```
main()
{
  List<Node<T>> n = new List<Node<T>>()
  bool found = false;
  T v = new T();
  foreach (Node<T> i in n)
  {
    if i.Content== v
    {
       found = true;
    }
  }
}
```

I understand in order to compare 2 instances of a class, I have to derive my class from IEquitable, but I would like to know if T belongs to predefined classes that we have been using all the times like int, double, string ... I do not want to redefine those classes but would expect the comparison to work and use the default comparator. How do I write the above so that c# would accept it and throw out a syntax error?

```
    if i.Content== v
    {
       found = true;
    }
```

I have tried

```
if (T)i.Content == (T)v 
{
  ...
}
```

The compiler does not seem to like it.
Actually, I did the following:

```
 Node<T> r = n.Where(x=> (T)x.Content==(T)v).FirstOrDefault()
```

The error I got was:
Operator == could not applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
Please advise.
Thanks!

Comment: Try .Equals instead of ==

Comment: Are you actually using `T` as your type in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `IEqualityComparer<T>`:

```
var comp = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
if (comp.Equals(i.Content, v)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! Just what I wanted! BTW, Abion47 solution seems to work too. His declaration is a bit more explicit?  It's too bad I can not mark both as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your `Node<T>` declaration to the following:

```
public class Node<T> where T : IEquatable<T>
```

Then you would be able to use:

```
if (i.Content.Equals(v))
    // ...
```

Comment: Your suggestion seems to work as well.. Thank you! You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify operators in generic constraints (with the exception of the parameter-less constructor, if you consider it an operator).

If you need some way of comparison, you need to use a method. Either use `Equals`, or add some interface like `IComparable<T>` as a generic constraint.